# Gateway stage variables in html mapping template

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I would like to access my stage variables in the mapping template that I create in one of the Gateway responses. I mention that the format of the template is **text/html** not **application/json**.

I know how to do it in json but cannot manage to make it work in html.

Any thoughts?

Thanks

Comment: It seems like it would be essentially the same, wouldn't it?  It's VTL either way, right?  What kind of results are you getting?

Comment: Not really. For example having this piece of html. It does not resolve the stage variable. `<html>
    <body>
    Click <a href="${stageVariables.url}">here</a> to login.
    </body>
</html>
`

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot, you were right int he sense that it is the same syntax. In my real example I was using the stage var name with an underscore and that was the problem. Changing it to camel case solved the issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue. I was using the stage variable name with an underscore and that was a problem. Changing it to camelcase did the job.

**Don't use like this**
`<a href="$stageVariables.api_url">here</a>`

**But like this**
`<a href="$stageVariables.apiUrl">here</a>`